# Best way of constructing batched Numpy array from CSV values?

Tags: numpy, csv, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, numpy-ndarray

I have a very large dataset in CSV format (500K+ lines and 6500+ columns), which looks something like this (everything is integer valued, followed by cast to float64 during the batch import loop):

```
1,7930472962,92,5,2,9471037239,67,2,1...8371097814,81,2,3
2,2091185638,92,5,2,3773622239,67,2,1...8378747918,81,2,3
```

So based on the length of the lines I can't fit everything into memory, I am streaming everything from CSV like this:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    sys.argv[1],
    batch_size = BATCHSIZE,
    column_names = SELECT_COLUMNS,
    column_defaults = DEFAULTS,
    label_name = LABEL_COLUMN,
    field_delim=',',
    use_quote_delim=True,
    na_value='',
    header=False,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True,
    shuffle_buffer_size=500,
    shuffle_seed=None,
    num_parallel_reads=1,
    sloppy=False,
    num_rows_for_inference=1000,
    compression_type=None,
    ignore_errors=False
)
```

I end up with a dict that I can then pull numpy arrays from in this fashion:

```
for batch, label in train_dataset:
    for key, value in batch.items():
       print(value.numpy())
```

Problem is, with each batch the Numpy arrays are grouping together everything by column whereas I need to have each CSV line from the batch converted into an ndarray, basically multiple nested ndarrays from the batch within an ndarray so that I can do something like this:

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = loader.load_data()
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=train_buf)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

I am having a difficult time understanding the transition to 2.0 espe, followed by the shuffle operation?cially insofar as tf.data is concerned. I think I need to pack each CSV line into tensor slices first, followed by then creating the dataset with tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "the Numpy arrays are grouping together everything by column whereas I need to have each CSV line from the batch converted into an ndarray, basically multiple nested ndarrays from the batch within an ndarray..." You want the entire thing to be 1 large array, and the code is currently giving you a list of columns?

Comment: I can pull ndarrays from each batch using something like this: `for batch, label in train_dataset.take(1):
    for key, value in batch.items():
        sys.stdout.write(str(value.numpy()))` [301 181 342][84620723843 84620723843 84620723843][50 50 50][7 8 2][4 4 4
][8320991093 8320991093 8320991093][2 5 3] problem is, the ndarrays are being grouped according to each column as opposed to a single ndarray for each CSV line, if that makes sense?

Comment: Could you describe the input data format? That might help make things clearer. Are you reading from a csv file?

Comment: Yes the input is a CSV file: 1,7930472962,92,5,2,9471037239,67,2,1...8371097814,81,2,3
2,2091185638,92,5,2,3773622239,67,2,1...8378747918,81,2,3

Comment: And so what is your desired output exactly? Could you manage the tensorflow stuff if you just got all the data from the csv as a numpy array?

Comment: Yeah I needed to get the entire batch into a single numpy array . x_train = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1).numpy()
is what i came up with

Comment: Okay, so in that case the issue is going tensorflow object -> numpy array, not csv file -> tensorflow object. Do you think you could include a longer example data file, so that I can try to recreate your situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(THECSVFILE.csv)` defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset), and then this is in `tf.data` type which can be fed to the models and it does not fill up your memory, however, if you shuffle the whole dataset then you might see some memory increment.